# A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object (configured limit: 1)

Tags: php

i ran into this error while running this MAJAction function with the route :

```
     MAJ_article:
            path: /Maj_article/{id}/{rate}
            defaults: { _controller: ArticleBundle:Article:MAJ }
```

the function is :

```
public function MAJAction($id,$rate){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);
    $article->setRating($rate);
    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();
    $serializer=new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]);
    $formatted= $serializer->normalize($article);

    if (!$article) {
        return new JsonResponse('There are no articles with the following id: ' . $id);
    }
    return new JsonResponse($formatted);
}
```

and the error is : A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "Proxies__CG__\ArticleBundle\Entity\Category" (configured limit: 1).

i think the cause of it is that the table article is the mother of the table category

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticleBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_category", referencedColumnName="id_category")
 */
private $category;
```

Comment: Is this question related to codenameone?
Shouldn't it be tagged php or something?